# Preventing Software Keyboard to show up when entering input on mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile

I would like to implement a virtual keyboard in React (non-native) JavaScript for my app, is there any way to prevent Phone's software keyboard showing up?

Comment: Add readonly attribute to input field

Comment: What do you mean by "app"? Native app? Website? PWA?

Comment: React PWA, sorry for lack of info will update